# Copying files recursively with skipping some directories in Python?

Tags: python

I want to copy a directory to another directory recursively. I also want to ignore some files (eg. all hidden files; everything starting with ".") and then run a function on all the other files (after copying them). This is simple to do in the shell, but I need a Python script.

I tried using shutil.copytree, which has ignore support, but I don't know how to have it do a function on each file copied. I might also need to check some other condition when copying so I can't just run the function on all the files once they are copied over. I also tried looking at os.walk but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Tell us what have you tried, and where did you stuck.

Comment: @utdemir ok, added a few lines, is this better?

Comment: What do you mean by "run a function on the files"? Are you going to open and read them, or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) to iterate over each file, apply your custom filtering function and copying over only the ones you care.

> ```
> os.walk(top[, topdown=True[, onerror=None[, followlinks=False]]])
> ```
>
> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).

You can add all copied files to a list and use it to run you custom script or run the script after each copy operation.

This should get you started:

```
import os

def filterls(src, filter_func):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for f in files:
            if filter_func(f):
                path = os.path.join(root, f)
                yield path[len(src)+1:]
```

It takes a path to a directory and a function which takes a single parameter. If the function returns False for the passed filename, the file is ignored.

You can try it in a python interpreter like this:

```
# Get a list of all visible files rooted in the 'path/to/the/dir' directory
print list(filterls('path/to/the/dir', lambda p: not p.startswith('.')))
```

Comment: I tried os.walk but I got a bit confused. Could you perhaps provide an example?

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Python 2.6 or higher, you can simply use `shutil.copytree` and its `ignore` argument. Since it gets passed all the files and directories, you can call your function from there, unless you want it to be called *right after* the file is copied.

If that is the case, the easiest thing is to copy and modify the `copytree` code.

Comment: I'd like to support Python 2.5 as well, but it isn't a hard requirement. Also, see my edit to the answer, but I couldn't figure out how to apply a custom function to every copied file (meeting some condition).